# Check scrollpoint each pixel is scrolled

Tags: javascript, onscroll

I need your help again. A try to code something like this:

I got an imaginary point on screen in pixel (lets say half of body) and I got a element in body. I want to alert if the elements TOP hits the imaginary line and alert if the elements bottom leave imaginary line.

I got something to work (for hit the line) but it only works a few times, but if I scroll fast it doesn't work. If I scroll very very slow and exactly the alert appears:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    // A POINT I SET On SCREEN --> IN THIS CASE HALF SIZE OF BODY
    var halfBody = $("body").height() / 2;

    if ($(window).scrollTop() == halfBody) alert('HIER');
});
```

I think the problem is the exact pixels i try to match. I think with scrolling I haven't always the exact pixels.

How can this be done so that elements top cross the line `alert('element top hits the line')` and elements bottom leave the line `alert('no element leaving the line');` ?

I hope you understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Scroll events are trigger happy and handing each even can overwhelm your handler.
Try using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce)/underscore debnounce/threshould to handle them every X milliseconds.
It's a common practice to scroll handling in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a nice solution with caching variables and a set timeout:

```
var timer;  
var windowHeight = $(window).height();  
var triggerHeight = 0.5 * windowHeight;


$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(timer) {
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
    }

    timer = window.setTimeout(function() {

        // this variable changes between callbacks, so we can't cache it
        var y = $(window).scrollTop() ;

        if(y > triggerHeight) {

        }           


        if( $(window).scrollTop() == 0 ) { // IF HITS TOP OF PAGE

        }

    }, 10);
});
```

maybe it helps someone!